# Using JQuery to get anchor parameters from all links on page and replacing href of target link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to obtain a set of href parameters from several different anchor links on a page and then pass those parameters to a target link. I believe I've arrived at about a 95% solution but I'm unable to pass all link parameters, it's only applying the parameter of the last anchor on the page.

When I run `document.write(paramstr);` inside the first function, I get all the parameters I'm looking for but when I run it inside the second function I'm only getting the last parameter. Perhaps I need to incorporate a loop inside the first function to append all the parameters so they don't get overwritten?

Here is the HTML & JS code I'm using:

```
    <!--This is the target link-->
    <a href="#" id="pay-all-auctions"><button class="button">
    Pay For All Auction Items
    </button>
    </a>
    <!--This is an example of an anchor link; about 20+ of these throughout the page-->
    <a  href="/my-account/my-auction/?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11364" 
        class="auction_add_to_cart_button button alt" 
        id="yith-wcact-auction-won-auction"> Add to cart </a>
```

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var href;
        var paramstr;
        $('a.auction_add_to_cart_button').each(function(){    // parse each link
            href = $(this).attr('href');   // get the href of the anchor
            for (var i = 0; i < href.length; i++) {
            paramstr = href.split('/')[3]; // get the parameter of interest
            }
        }); 

        $("a[href*=#]").attr("href", function(){
            // replace the target link href with the parameters of interest
            return href.replace('#',paramstr); 
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here is the expected output in console:

```
?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11364
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11361
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11357
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11356
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11365
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11376
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11358
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11354
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11345
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11408
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11407
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11406
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11405
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11404
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11398
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11397
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11396
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11395
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11394
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11393
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11392
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11391
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11390
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11389
(index):640 ?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11388
```

Comment: 1- You need to provide some html code .. And what is the `href` looks like and what is the expected `href` should look like .. 2- I think the `.attr('href'...` part should be inside `.each` loop .. 3- I think no need to use `for` loop .. 4- Also what is the relation between `'a.auction_add_to_cart_button'` and the target link?

Comment: Please edit the question again with .. You want to replace `#` with `What you expect  here?`

Comment: Sorry , Ok let me clarify my question .. you want the `href="#"` to replace `#` with `yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11361, yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11364 , ...` or `11361 , 11364 , ....` or what??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the result to be `?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11363&?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11364&?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11365&?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11366` I don't know how you'll work with something like this specially its not a valid url and the same parameter name but anyway you can use the next code to get this result

- No need to use `for` loop
- Also no need to use `function` and `replace` in `.attr`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var paramstr ="";
  $('a.auction_add_to_cart_button').each(function(){    // parse each link
    var href = $(this).attr('href');   // get the href of the anchor
    paramstr += href.split('/')[3]+'&'; // get the parameter of interest
    
  });
   paramstr = paramstr.slice(0, -1); // remove the last & 
   console.log(paramstr);
   //$("#pay-all-auctions").attr("href", paramstr);
   $("#pay-all-auctions").attr("data-auctions", paramstr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--This is the target link -->
<a href="#" id="pay-all-auctions"><button class="button">
    Pay For All Auction Items
</button>
</a>
<!--This is an example of an anchor link; about 20+ of these throughout the page -->
<a href="/my-account/my-auction/?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11363" class="auction_add_to_cart_button button alt" id="yith-wcact-auction-won-auction"> Add to cart </a>
<a href="/my-account/my-auction/?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11364" class="auction_add_to_cart_button button alt" id="yith-wcact-auction-won-auction"> Add to cart </a>
<a href="/my-account/my-auction/?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11365" class="auction_add_to_cart_button button alt" id="yith-wcact-auction-won-auction"> Add to cart </a>
<a href="/my-account/my-auction/?yith-wcact-pay-won-auction=11366" class="auction_add_to_cart_button button alt" id="yith-wcact-auction-won-auction"> Add to cart </a>
```

**Finally:** The result It's not a valid value to add to the anchor href with this type of values you can use `data` attribute instead

**Additional Information**

- The parameter in `href` shoud look like `?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3`
- If you have a same parameter in the url `?p1=1&p1=2` for example php `$_GET['p1']` will return the last parameter value